# Behance Oauth Token Request Not Redirecting

Tags: behance-api

I'm having trouble getting an oauth token from Behance.  I'm familiar with how oauth works and I've followed the steps outlined here: https://www.behance.net/dev/authentication

My redirect_uri matches what I setup in my behance account, and is it is also url-encoded.

https://www.behance.net/v2/oauth/authenticate?client_id=*MYCLIENTID*&redirect_uri=*URLENCODED_REDIRECT*&scope=wip_read|wip_write&state=54fde3ee43d79f4d1d1944f5984d686e

When I go to this page, I'm getting an "Oops! No longer supported" and "This page has been removed."  Is oauth even available?

My app is set to development, but I should be able to access my own account with that setting.  I'd figure this is pretty straight forward, but maybe I'm missing something.  I've contacted their support and have received no feedback.

Comment: I get a 404 page on https://www.behance.net/dev/authentication